# Replace Views prev/next pagination with image arrows

Tags: 7, views, theming, media, paging

Is there a template that would allow me to replace Views' prev/next text pagination with image arrows instead? I could do it with CSS but I don't feel that is ultimately an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [theme_pager_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_link/7) function to override the core pager link. Or you can have a look at this article that may be helpful: https://www.drupal.org/node/318565

Answer (score 0):

In general use CSS for this - not bad solution.
But if you want use a changes in the output - You need use special function in your template.php your theme. For example for "mini_pager" - You need implementation the [theme_views_mini_pager()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/theme_views_mini_pager/7) function. For another pagers use the same method.